# iphone best practice, how to load multiple high quality images

Tags: iphone, image, load, uiimageview

I have about 20-ish high quality images (~3840x5800 px) that I need to load in a simple gallery type app. The user clicks a button and the next image is loaded into the UIImageView.

I currently use [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] which takes about 6 seconds to load each image in the simulator :(

if I use [UIImage imageNamed:] it takes even longer to load but caches the images which means its quicker if the user wishes to see the same images again. But it may cause memory problems later with all that caching crashing my app.

I want to know whats the best practice for loading these? I'm experimenting with reducing image file size as much as is possible but I really need them to be high quality image for the purpose of the app (zoomable, etc.).

Thanks for any advice

[EDIT]

Hey again guys,

Thanks for all ye're advice. The project's spec's have changed a little. Now as well as displaying the images they firstly have to be zoomed in to a particular spot and when the user taps next it zooms out and then displays the next image. So I'm not sure if the proposed solutions fits?

Comment: If you need them that large because you want them to be zoomable, I'd suggest you fragment them and load only the pieces currently in view like google maps style. Something like 100x100 should do the trick.

Comment: thanks NS6String, I'm working on another project but will get back to this over the next week and will have a look into all you've said and repost here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) recommend against trying to load single images that are larger than 1024x1024. You should look into using [CATiledLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) instead, to load pieces of the images as needed.

Comment: There is a great WWDC10 video on using this. Also, CIMGF just had a good post on how to do it. http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/

Comment: Hey Anomie and Walter, thanks for the advice, I'm working on another project but will get back to this over the next week and will have a look into all you've said and repost here

Comment: @walter - do you have the link to the WWDC10 video about the photoscroller? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/index.php and log in with your developer account.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this Apple sample:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080

It shows how to load big images, breaking them in tiles for different zoom levels.

Comment: Hey Swisstricky, I'm working on another project but will get back to this over the next week and will have a look into all you've said and repost here, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can't see all those pixels at any given time, so there is no need to load them all.  Load lower-res copies ("big-thumbnails") to view the complete image, then selected sub-tiles, maybe of 2 or more different resolution sets, after the user zooms in.

The CATiledLayer API may be able to handle some of the latter for you.

Comment: thanks hotpaw2, I'm working on another project but will get back to this over the next week and will have a look into all you've said and repost here